# Pandas value counts save output to file

Tags: pandas, numpy

I use pandas's value_counts() method to get the number of times each value in a column appears. Although the output looks like what I expected, attempting to save it using numpy savetxt or pandas to_csv returns only one column (with counts). I'd like to be able to save both.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way would be to use reset_index and then to_csv

```
df['key'].value_counts().reset_index().to_csv('df.csv')
```

Comment: in case you want them to be sorted by index you can do `sort_index()` instead of `reset_index()`